# Movie where a videogame becomes real

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember seeing a movie in the late 90's to early 2000's about a video game company working on a video game.  I think lightning hits the building or something happens and the game becomes real.  People star being killed off.  In the end a woman that was new to the company ends up defeating the game and survives.

The movie is not [Stay Alive](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0441796/).

Comment: Its got me remind of Tom and jerry's episode where they both got stuck in video-game because of lighting strike. BTW can you tell about the movie genre.

Comment: Its not stay alive and i don't think its tron or Spy Kids3 but i think it may be Existenz?

Comment: @ankitsharma oliver_c's answer is the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could be [**How to Make a Monster**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Make_a_Monster_%282001_film%29) *(2001)*:

> [image: How To Make A Monster]
>
> A computer game company hires three eccentric programmers to complete an unfinished game called *Evilution*...
>
> On a dark and stormy night, an electrical surge brings the motion-capture monster suit to life and it becomes controlled by the computer AI. The monster then begins to stalk and kill the team throughout the lab as if they were actually playing the game.   [[Source](http://www.popcornpictures.co.uk/how-to-make-a-monster-2001/)]

- [Watch the trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbnqW0U7Zt4)

Comment: That's exactly it!  Awesome!  I'm going to see about rewatching this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the film you are looking for is Brainscan with Edward Furlong. You may remember him from the Terminator films.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109327/

Furlong is a highschool student, the sort that is always in trouble. he comes into possession of a video game called Brainscan. Playing it causes events to become real and the character in the video game named The Trickster tries to control the kid.

Comment: not it, but definataely a nice entry to have here.

Comment: Figured it wasn't right after hitting add...:C)